# In SSMS, how can I find a string containing an asterisk, some text, then another asterisk?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

We have a database with lots of SPs and Views, most of which are great, but some have dodgy criteria in (which a previous employee transferred from MS Access using a translation program).

For example, there are SPs with critera like:

```
WHERE dbo.something NOT LIKE '*TEST*'
```

The person that set this up meant:

```
WHERE dbo.something NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
```

I've found a few already using this method, but I've had to type the exact text. Replacing the word TEST with a % Character does not work (% returns 0 records, TEST returns some records).

```
USE [databasename]
SELECT @SEARCHSTRING = '*TEST*', @notcontain = ''

SELECT DISTINCT sysobjects.name AS [Object Name] 
,case when sysobjects.xtype = 'P' then 'Stored Proc'
when sysobjects.xtype = 'TF' then 'Function'
when sysobjects.xtype = 'TR' then 'Trigger'
when sysobjects.xtype = 'V' then 'View'
end as [Object Type]
,USER_NAME(sysobjects.uid) AS trigger_owner 
--,s.name AS table_schema 
,OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) AS table_name 
FROM sysobjects,syscomments
WHERE sysobjects.id = syscomments.id
AND sysobjects.type in ('P','TF','TR','V')
AND sysobjects.category = 0
AND CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,syscomments.text)>0
AND ((CHARINDEX(@notcontain,syscomments.text)=0 
or CHARINDEX(@notcontain,syscomments.text)<>0))
```

I would like to know if anyone knows a way in which I can search for a string, in all objects, which has an asterisk, some text and another asterisk.
Thanks v much

Comment: Just so we're clear, can you give some examples of text you want to match? And some edges cases of what you don't want to match?

Comment: Did you try `... syscomments.text LIKE N'%*TEST*%'` or `... syscomments.text LIKE N'%*%*%'` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson Hi Gord, Yes I tried both of those already, but it returned nothing, whereas if I use like '%*TEST*%' I'm able to identify a few Stored Procedures.

Comment: @Bohemian Hi Bohemian, I would want to match any of the following: '*TEST*'  or '*BOB*' or '*FOO*'. I would not want to match '*TEST' or 'BOB*' or 'FOO'. I'm just trying to capture SPs which people have imported from Access SQL incorrectly. In this case, where they have not substituted a % for *. Thanks

Comment: `LIKE '%*%*%'` should work. Does it match SP that are known contain this pattern?

Comment: @ben what do you mean *"I'm able to identify a few Stored Procedures"*? Exactly how are you using your query? Are you querying catalog tables or something? Can you post actual data or even better actual insert statements so we know exactly what data you're searching? I suspect the problem is that the data is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm using the query to identify objects (SP's, views, functions, triggers) which contain a string, containing multiple asterisks. For example, there was an SP someone had written, with a like condition in the where clause written as   WHERE database.dbo.table NOT LIKE '*TEST*'. The writer was familiar with MS Access and had assumed that the asterisks were wild cards in TSQL like they are in Access. I've since found a few more instances of asterisks in place of percent characters, and I suspect there are more hiding in the various databases - so I'm trying to track them down. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked a long ago but heres a possible simple solution to your question :::

```
select sys.objects.name,sys.objects.type_desc, syscomments.id from sys.objects 
inner join
syscomments
    on sys.objects.object_id = syscomments.id
WHERE syscomments.text like '%[^/]*%*[^/]%'    --here the * that is following the / and preceding /has been ignored because i dont think you want to replace the comments that has /* ....... */
```

hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

This was given to me by another developer.  Maybe this will do the trick?

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = 'Coincide'--'Absolute Value of the Difference' --'DOIRteDc' --'Smartin1' -- 'Rgillesp'--'--'## YOUR STRING HERE ##'

-- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
-- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
-- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
-- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
-- Updated and tested by Tim Gaunt
-- http://www.thesitedoctor.co.uk
-- http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/02/19/Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database+Updated.aspx
-- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0, SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2010
-- Date modified: 03rd March 2011 19:00 GMT
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT distinct ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: Hi Duston, thanks for your suggestion but this is not really what I need. I need some SQL to identify strings with an Asterisk, then some text, then another asterisk.

Comment: Can't you use that and just change the SeachStr2 line?

Comment: Possibly Duston, but I cannot just change the content of SearchStr2 (in your case a string made of the word 'Coincide', in my case a string made of and asterisk, some text, and another asterisk. Usually I would write this as '*%*', but SQL server doesn't recognize the % character as a wild card in this case, as it usually would. I'm sure my syntax is wrong, but I'm not sure what else to try. Thanks